# esxi 5 monitoring

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm new to esxi/vmware world. Have few question about monitoring esxi host. Now I'm using trial versian esxi 5.1

1. I can see performance charts in vShpere client. Cool. But I want to export this raw data (raw - I mean cvs,txt or some format which I can parse later) to other server to be able to parse this data later and create custom charts. (please do not advise to try vCenter, I need custom charts etc.)
2. I could run esxtop in batch mode and use this data... But... How does vShpere client performance charts work? Where client takes data for charts? So if I will use esxtop batch mode it will add extra load to server. Is it possible to use same source as vSphere client use for charts?
3. There is /var/lib/vmware/hostd/stats/hostAgentStats-20.stats file. Its looks like it is binary format. As I understood it is exactly data which I need?!?! Any ideas how to parse it?

Thanks!

PS: maybe some one know where to find, if there is one, info about processes running on esxi host?

Comment: What insight do you hope to gain? Are you using a monitoring solution for your physical servers?

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008065 describes configuring SNMP on ESX(i) hosts, though how much useful information you can expect is honestly pretty suspect.

If you are comfortable with some more development efforts, the VI Perl SDK is where to go: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/

It has some sample and very useful tools for managing hosts, clusters, VMs, etc, from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

Try using visualesxtop, you might be able to use it as a batch source.

https://labs.vmware.com/flings/visualesxtop

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.